# .Net Core Regex Replace returning different from localhost

Tags: excel, regex, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, parseint

something weird is happening, I have a value from an Excel file and I use Regex.Replace() to transform the value into what I need, locally everything works fine but when I publish the return is different from Regex.Replace():

Given this value: 376900€

I use this code:

```
x = Regex.Replace(sheet.Cells['D' + row].Text.Replace("€", ""), @"\s+", "");
                        
var Amount = int.Parse(x);
```

Locally x is: 376900

but when published in a app service x is: 376,900, which throws an exception while parsing to int.

I solved it without using Regex.Replace() but was wondering why is this happening? is it because the server is in North Europe and Regex.Replace() uses some UK conversion or something?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be using Excel Interop, possibly the culture/format of the Excel file is different when opened by your localPC vs the app server. This may mean that the text of the Excel file shows "376,900€". Look into using 'sheet.Cells['D' + row].Value.Replace', since the Value property takes the underlying value rather than formatting. I suspect the sheet has a Value 376900, which has been formatted and you are getting weird results

Comment: @MacroMarc it probably is the Excel Interop culture int the server location, if you want create an answear and I will accept it

Comment: @JasonPan your answear helps saying its not from Regex but did not answear, suggests for me to debbug and see the values which I already know and are expressed in my question... While MacroMarc comment goes right to the point.

Comment: @MarchalPT Remote debug, not in local.

Comment: @JasonPan if I had not debugged remotely how I knew the x value in the app?

Comment: @MarchalPT You get `376900€` from azure ? Not get it in local by debug ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232332/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-marchalpt).

Comment: The point I make is that you should consider using sheet.Cells['D' + row].Value instead of sheet.Cells['D' + row].Text It is not advisable in most cases to use .Text Apart from tackling the culture issue, if you do not NEED to use .Text, then try to use either .Value2 or .Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My test result. Azure app service reture value same as local.**

[image]

So MacroMarc's comment is quite right. It should be the data format of this field in the Excel file. When debugging locally, I get `376900€` (according to the local culture/format).

## **Suggestion**

You can deploy your azure web app with debug model. And use remote debugging, to check the value of `sheet.Cells['D' + row].Text`.  I believe that after debugging, you will find the answer you want.